# Debian 11: Brightness does not work on ASUS VivoBook

Tags: debian, nvidia, xfce, intel, brightness

I know there are many other similar topics. However,  I've tried all other solutions such as changing kernel parameters in grub file, using `xbacklight`, etc. However, there is no success yet. I'm pretty sure that I missed something else but I couldn't figure it out.

I'm using *Debian 11* with the *XFCE* desktop. Pop-menu appears when I press `fn+(f4/f5)` to decrease and increase the screen's brightness, However, the functionality does not work and the brightness is stuck on maximum.

Meanwhile, I could control the brightness with the help of `xrandr`, but as far as I know, `xrandr` controls the brightness by changing software parameters, not really the hardware layer.
I've installed Nvidia drivers(including *free/nonfree* related packages).

Here are some outputs of commands which might be helpful:

```bsh
# ls /sys/class/backlight/
intel_backlight
```

```bsh
# nvidia-smi
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 470.182.03   Driver Version: 470.182.03   CUDA Version: 11.4     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA GeForce ...  Off  | 00000000:02:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   51C    P0    N/A /  N/A |      0MiB /  2002MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|  No running processes found                                                 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

```bsh
# /etc/default/grub:

# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT=5
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="acpi_backlight=native" # I've tried other parameters, but none of them works
...
```

```bsh
# lspci -nn | egrep -i "3d|display|vga":

0000:00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation TigerLake GT2 [Iris Xe Graphics] [8086:9a49] (rev 01)
0000:02:00.0 3D controller [0302]: NVIDIA Corporation GP107M [GeForce MX350] [10de:1c94] (rev a1)
```